# Custom event logging for Javascript frameworks

Tags: javascript, event-handling, prototypejs, dom-events, custom-eventlog

Imagine I have a web application with nice components coded up with your favorite Javascript library. I make heavy use of custom events to reduce the dependencies between these components so you can easily place them in multiple contexts, repeat them on the page, and/or nest them as I see fit.

This is a lovely picture, but debugging can be quite a pain, as I haven't found a way to do logging of my custom events. Ideally, I would like to be able to turn on logging in my framework of choice (I use Prototype, currently), and then get a running log of fired and observed events at any point or points in the DOM.

I've been discussing this with other F2E's and a few approaches have been tried:

- [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) is a bookmarklet that does a good job of visualizing where events are bound, but doesn't offer a runtime log.
- [Antenna](http://crossbrowser.blogspot.com/2009/05/prototypejs-decoupling-solution-antenna.html) Is just such a log, but seems a bit buggy and requires modification of the prototype library itself, which feels like a hack.

How do I go about getting the custom logging I want?

Answer (score 1):

You probably using some X.fireEvent method which is (probably-not familiar with your FW) defined in the Object.prototype.
I would investigate the approach to override this one method with your version which will do the log stuff.

Comment: This seems like the start of an implementation in jQuery, am I right?

Comment: I am not familiar with JQ, but in Mootools I would simply do "extend" of the [fire] method. I assume there is something similar in JQ.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Prototype, I would [wrap](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/wrap) a logging function around `document.fire`.

Comment: In Prototype, I think you would wrap `Event.observe`. Others have tried this will little success, though, which is why the author of Antenna actually modified the script directly rather than simply doing this wrapping. I'm looking for a working implementation out there that doesn't modify the library files directly.